# iOS - Change the height of text field inside a UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have this layout

[image]

And I want to resize the height of every text field inside, but I cant do it on inspector. Its something about constraints?

Can someone help me with this thing?

Here is my tree of components

[image]

Answer (score 1):

yes you will need to set height constraints for the stuff that is in your stack view. Have a look at this:[How to set height of containers in stack view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049529/how-to-set-height-of-containers-in-stack-view)

Comment: Might be simpler to say: *"Start by setting the `Distribution` of "Stack View Main" to `Fill Equally`"* instead of pointing to another question.

Comment: but the reference shows context and explanations that would be redundant to repeat. now the OP has something to read/study that broadens horizons